# Email addresses export from outlook - only folder by folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I want to take all the email addresses my sales guys have ever communicated with and dedupe against my marketing db to ensure we have everyone. I see I have download by folder but they've each many folders. Is there a way of doing the download agianst their address from the server or not folder by folder ?

Answer (score 0):

On my per experience, it couldn't be achieved directly, as workaround, you need let your sales colleagues add the email addresses to the contact, then export the contact.